# Play Framework 2.5: View model bind request returns 'null'

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I tried to bind my view with model using bindFromRequest() but view and  model are not bind , model gives null value.

This is my controller

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.Form;
import views.html.*;
import models.Login;
import controllers.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

public class LoginController extends Controller {

    public Result authenticate() {
        Form<Login> loginForm = Form.form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();

        //  password value is return null.
        System.out.println("password :: "+loginForm.get().password); 
        if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
          return ok(login.render("Error in login" ,Form.form(Login.class)));
        } else  { }
    }
}
```

This is Model Login.java

```
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Login extends Model {

  @Id
  public String id;
  public String email;
  public String password;

}
```

This is Login View login.html :

```
     <form class="login-form" action="@routes.LoginController.authenticate" method="post">

      <h1><a href="@routes.LoginController.index" id="logo"><span>
        <img src="@routes.Assets.at("/images/logo-main.jpg")" alt="PUAthletics" height="42" >
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("/images/logo-main.jpg")"/></span></a></h1>
      <p class="loginMessage ">
      @message
      </p>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="@form("email").value" />
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      <button type="submit" class="submit-upld">Login</button>
     </form>
```

Comment: Can you share the `Login` model class

Comment: And also the view please

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you got NPE here:

```
System.out.println("password :: "+loginForm.get().password);
```

If so, that is because form has errors. You should check first if your form is valid:

```
if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
   return badRequest(login.render("Error in login" , loginForm);
}
```

and then retrieve your model. Consider scenario where invalid data type is passed into your form, in that case Play cant construct your model.